# Api for deleting

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, backend

```
const deleteContact=asyncHandler(async(req,res)=>{

    const contact=await Contact.findById(req.params.id);

    if(!contact){
        res.status(404);
        throw new Error("Contact Not foud");
    }

    await Contact.remove();
    res.status(200).json();
});
```

I'm trying to write the end point of the deleting contact but I'm not able to delete by using the above query.

Comment: Not able to delete in what way? Do you get an error, unexpected results, something else? Should it be `contact.remove();` rather than `Contact.remove();`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [mongoose v7.3.1 document](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html):

> The MongoDB driver's remove() function is deprecated in favor of
> deleteOne() and deleteMany(). This is to comply with the MongoDB CRUD
> specification, which aims to provide a consistent API for CRUD
> operations across all MongoDB drivers.

So use `deleteOne` instead of `remove`, as:

```
await Contact.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.id });
```

Updated code:

```
const deleteContact = asyncHandler(async(req,res) => {
    const contact=await Contact.findById(req.params.id);
    if(!contact){
        res.status(404);
        throw new Error("Contact Not found");
    }
    await Contact.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.id });
    res.status(200).json();
});
```